# Using fscanf() to get two values from a two column file

Tags: c, scanf

Hello everyone this is my first time posting on stack overflow and I am new to c so let me know if I am doing something wrong.

I am trying to use fscanf to put words from a file into my two string variables (currentUID and currentKey). But for some reason the value that was stored in currentUID (at my first comment) disappears when I use fscanf to give a value to my currentKey variable... I've been looking for a reason why this might be happening but so far I haven't been able to figure it out.  Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

```
while(!feof(fp))
{
    fscanf(fp, "%s", currentUID);
        //1 currentUID has correct value here...
    fscanf(fp, "%s", currentKey);
        //2 But currentUID has lost its value here. 
}
```

Here is an example of how the file is formatted:

```
421 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcde0

422 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcde1

423 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcde2

423 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcde3
```

All I am trying to do is have access to both values at the point of my second comment so I can pass them to another method. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: What are currentUID and currentKey defined to be?

Comment: Can we see the declarations for `currentUID` and `currentKey`?

Answer (score 0):

Read like following :

```
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s%s", currentUID,currentKey)==2)
{
   // printf("%s ", currentUID);
        //1 currentUID has correct value here...
   // printf("%s\n", currentKey);
        //2 But currentUID has lost its value here. 
}
```

**Edit**
Did you declare your variables correctly ?

`char currentUID[4],currentKey[33];`